# Is it faster or less memory intensive to limit data to one table in a database?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

SQL databases are often organized by tables. These tables have the columns and rows that store information. Does it take significantly more time to change from table to table than it would to use only one table? I am considering storing each user as a different table. There will not be many users in the database. There would be a password column and a column for all of their owned appliances. Is this a bad practice? Also: what should I do instead of this?

Potential duplicate: [A seperate table for the posts which each user has liked - practical or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607587/a-seperate-table-for-the-posts-which-each-user-has-liked-practical-or-not)

Reason it does not suit my needs: I do not know any alternatives to what I am doing.

```
Proposed database design          Traditional database design

Table: username123                 Table: login (only one table)
Password:       Appliances:        User:    Password:  Appliance1 ...
-----           -----              -----    -----      -----
-----           -----              -----    -----      -----
-----           -----              -----    -----      -----
        ...                                  ...
```

Comment: Don't confuse tables with actual data storage. A table can be split and optimised _transparently_ in many ways. It is not necessary to have physically different tables. You can for example use table partitioning, which, behind the scenes, splits a table. You also use various types of indexes. It's a common mistake to try and come up with some kind of performance optimised schema when, firstly, this can be done transparently below the schema level, and secondly, you shouldn't be doing any performance optmisation until you have actual data and queries to measure against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not store each user as a different table!  This is a maintenance nightmare and hurts performance.

You cannot:

- Query all users easily.
- Set up foreign key relationships.
- Modify the user table.
- Easily optimize using indexes.
- And the list goes on.

Because of the underlying structure of SQL, it is usually more efficient to put data into one large table rather than a zillion small tables.

You have an entity called `users`.  You should have a table to represent that entity.

Comment: Thank you! This answered much of my question.

Answer (score 0):

The table or a set of related tables are used to represent an entity, usually logical. Different members of this entity e.g. different users in that case, those are always stored vertically as data rows into the table(s). Having more than one table is not for storing members of the entity but parts of the entity that exceeds the upper limit of 1 item. That is, the user (1 item) must be stored into 1 table called e.g. Users but user phone number(s) which may exceed the limit of 1 item per user it's better to be stored at a second table called UsersPhoneNums, related to table Users as Users.PrimaryID = UserPhoneNums.UsersPrimaryID (foreign key constraint - any row in UsersPhoneNums (any phone number) belongs to a row in Users (a user)). If not use UsersPhoneNums table, you must preset the quantity of phone numbers per user (e.g. only 3 like home, work and mobile)and add 3 columns into table Users like WorkPhone, HomePhone and MobilePhone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Stefanos! Duly noted.